# Start/Stop a Discord-Bot in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to create a command to start and stop my test Discord-Bot but have no idea on how to do a stop command. Maybe anyone can help me there? Here is my code.

```
if(args[0] === "start") {
        child.exec("node test.js", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
                return;
            }
            if (stderr) {
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        });
        
    }else {
        if(args[0] === "stop") {
            //stop the bot
        }
    }
```